# Elasticsearch - Document count fluctuates on update documents

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using mongo river to push data from mongo to elasticsearch. When I do indexing, initially all documents are indexed from mongo.
So when I run

```
  curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty"
```

I get exactly say 20000 docs.

Changes are always being pushed into elasticsearch from mongo using mongo-river.(internally it is using bulk update api)

But after 10-15 mins, there is always difference in around 5 to 10 documents.

Documents count in elasticsearch never will become exact 20000.
It keeps on fluctuating.

Can anyone help me, what is the problem here

Comment: Are you sure that all your documents are being indexed? The bulk API has a way of checking if there are failures (you have to use the Java API for this). You can write some code to index the documents using the Java API, and investigate where is the error. Also, do an index refresh before checking your indices.

Comment: Yes. Initially all documents are indexed. But after sometime say 15 mins. It keeps on fluctuating. Sometimes differences might be 5 documents, later it becomes 6 documents and then 2 documents.
Mongo river plugin is the one which pushes data from mongo to ES using bulk update api.